# LDAP auth for apache and viewvc

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, ldap

I am newer to Ubuntu and Apache. I know I have a config that works, if I put the directory /var/www/html and go to that directory I get prompted for creds and they work. What I can not figure out is how to make this work for the viewvc site. I have tried numerous directories including root of www and /usr/lib/cgi-bin I can not seem to get it to prompt for username when I go to /cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi